# How to let liquibase generate IDs for @GeneratedValue(GenerationType.TABLE) properties?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, liquibase

we are currently pretty stuck with the following situation:

We have several JPA-mapped entities where the IDs get autogenerated by means of `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)` annotations, ORM is Hibernate 4. Additionally we are using liquibase for managing database migrations.

Now we have a situation where a migration involves the creation of a new table and data from existing tables has to be migrated to the new table. New table (i. e. according entity) has named strategy for ID generation. The question is how we can savely create IDs for the newly added rows within the liquibase migration so that the following constraints are met:

- it must be possible to generate an SQL script (via liquibase) that performs the migration (so custom classes for migration can not be used)
- migration must run against HSQLDB and Oracle
- of course, Hibernate ID generation must not be corrupted

Any help on this issue is greatly appreciated!